# Chrome Apps: webview not working inside sandbox

Tags: google-chrome-app

I just started building Chrome Apps, i've gone through `sandbox` and `webview` examples but have no idea why `webview` is not working inside `sandbox`. When `webview` is placed in `main/window.html` it works fine. Even `sandbox` included as `<iframe>` works fine, but `webview` placed inside `sandbox` is not working. Have no idea why it's showing `white empty space`.
Then I tried with replacing `webview` with `<iframe>` inside `sandbox` even then it didn't worked. can Some explain why this happens in brief

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox):

> A sandboxed page will not have access to extension or app APIs

`<webview>` tag is part of the Apps API. It's not available to normal pages, and as such not available to anything sandboxed.

Comment: Hi Xan, Thanks for  the information provided, even i am unable to load video in `<iframe>'  from the `<webview>` but i am able to access other websites  using `<iframe>`  in the `<webview>`